# How to extract JSON from a binary protobuf?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, protocol-buffers, spark-structured-streaming

Considering a Apache Spark 2.2.0 Structured Stream as:

```
jsonStream.printSchema()
root
 |-- body: binary (nullable = true)
```

The data inside body is of type Protocol Buffers v2 and a nested JSON. It looks like

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Data {
  required string data = 1;
}

message List {
  repeated Data entry = 1;
}
```

How can I extract the data inside Spark to "further" process it?

I looked into [ScalaPB](https://scalapb.github.io/sparksql.html), but as I run my code in Jupyter couldn't get the ".proto" code to be included inline. I also do not know how to convert a DataFrame to an RDD on a stream. Trying `.rdd` failed because of a streaming source.

*Update 1*: I figured out how to generate Scala files from protobuf specifications, using the console tool of ScalaPB. Still I'm not able to import them as of a "type mismatch".

Comment: Could you describe how to generate Scala files from the protobuf spec? Could you describe how you try to import them for Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Write a user-defined function (UDF) to deserialize the binary field (of protobuf with a JSON) to JSON.

Think of the serialized `body` (in `binary` format) as a table column. Forget about Structured Streaming for a moment (and streaming Datasets).

Let me then rephrase the question to the following:

> How to convert (aka cast) a value in binary to [here-your-format]?

Some formats are directly `cast`-able which makes converting binaries to strings as easy as follows:

```
$"body" cast "string"
```

If the string is then a JSON or unixtime you could use built-in "converters", i.e. [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) like `from_json` or `from_unixtime`.

The introduction should give you a hint how to do conversions like yours.

> The data inside body is of type Protocol Buffers v2 and a nested JSON.

To deal with such fields (protobuf + json) you'd have to write a Scala function to decode the "payload" to JSON and create a user-defined function (UDF) using [udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@udf(f:org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1%5B_,_%5D,returnType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction):

> **udf(f: UDF1[_, _], returnType: DataType): UserDefinedFunction** Defines a Java UDF1 instance as user-defined function (UDF). The caller must specify the output data type, and there is no automatic input type coercion. By default the returned UDF is deterministic. To change it to nondeterministic, call the API `UserDefinedFunction.asNondeterministic()`.

Then use functions like `from_json` or `get_json_object`.

To make your case simpler, write a single-argument function that does the conversion and wrap it into a UDF using `udf` function.

---

> Trying .rdd failed because of a streaming source.

Use [Dataset.foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit) or [foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@foreachPartition(f:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EUnit):Unit).

> **foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Applies a function f to all rows.
>
> **foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Applies a function f to each partition of this Dataset.

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable, do you have any example you can point me to? Considering Protobuf needs "mapper" classes I still have to import my generated code am I right, or do I miss something?

Comment: I've never worked with protobuf so I can't help here. That's however outside Spark's reach and _"if you can do it in Scala, you should use udf in Spark"_ applies here.